# Filtering the complicated data in an array and return a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have an array like this :

```
const arr = [
              { name: 'A', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}]},
              { name: 'B', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}]},
              { name: 'C', accounts: [{id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}]},
];
```

and I would like to modify this array like this :

```
const arr = [
              { name: 'A', accounts: {joint: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}], individual: [{id: 1, data: {}}]}},
              { name: 'B', accounts: {joint: [], individual: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}]}},
              { name: 'C', accounts: {joint: [{id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}], individual: []}},
];
```

which means, putting the same accounts id in an joint and non repeated id object in an individual.

This is how I tried :

```
              for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
                const compareValue = test[standard].id;
                if (compareValue === test[i].id) {
                   joint.push(test[i]);
                }
                standard++;
            }
            if (joint.length > 0) {
                if (joint.filter(account => account.id === test[standard].id).length > 0) {
                    joint.push(test[standard]);
                } else {
                    individual.push(test[standard]);
                }
            }
            if (joint.length === 1) {
                const item = joint[0];
                individual.push(item);
                joint.pop();
            }
        } else {
            individual.push(test[0]);
        }
```

Could you help me to figure out what i have missed?
Thanks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh I'm going to edit the question. It was supposed to be an object. But feel free to suggest a better structure if you have an idea. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yep, an object is probably the most easily understandable structure, that's the sort of thing I'd do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your output `accounts` property is meant to be an object:

I'd split the problem into chunks first. If you can figure out a way to transform an individual `accounts` array into the desired output structure, you're most of the way there (and the rest is just a simple `.map`). So, we just need to turn

```
[{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}]
```

into

```
{joint: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}], individual: [{id: 1, data: {}}]}
```

One option is to iterate over the input objects, and just count up the number of occurrences of each id. Then, once you have a count, just iterate over the input objects again, looking up the count for each one. If the count is 1, push it to an `individual` array, else push it to a `joint` array:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: 'A', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}]},
  { name: 'B', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}]},
  { name: 'C', accounts: [{id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}]},
];

const transformAccounts = (inputAccounts) => {
  const occurrencesOfId = inputAccounts.reduce((a, { id }) => {
    a[id] = (a[id] || 0) + 1;
    return a;
  }, {});
  const joint = [];
  const individual = [];
  inputAccounts.forEach((obj) => {
    if (occurrencesOfId[obj.id] > 1) {
      joint.push(obj);
    } else {
      individual.push(obj);
    }
  });
  return { joint, individual };
};

const output = arr.map(({ name, accounts }) => ({
  name,
  accounts: transformAccounts(accounts)
}));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: It works wonderfully, thank you so much. But could you briefly explain the block of code where occurrencesOfId variable is? I am trying to understand how does that reduce function works there. Thank you.

Comment: It's an object indexed by `id`, whose values are the number of occurrences of each ID. Eg, for `A`, it's `{ 0: 2, 1: 1 }`. For `C`, it's `{ 2: 3 }`. The `(a[id] || 0)` looks up the existing count-in-progress for that ID on the accumulator, and if it doesn't exist, resolves to 0 instead. Then, 1 is added to the whole expression, and assigned back to the accumulator. It's a pretty common pattern https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+count+up+occurrences+into+object+reduce+javascript+stackoverflow+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Uses really similar logic as above answer, just the code is little different, it might help you better understand how you can work with data.

So first step is that you must create some sort of table of occurrences.
Then based on that sort the accounts between joint and individual. 
You did not specify if you want to merge the data or they are just duplicates.

```js
const arr = [
    { name: 'A', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}]},
    { name: 'B', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}]},
    { name: 'C', accounts: [{id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}]},
];

let newArray = arr.map( value => {
    let accounts = {
        joint: [],
        individual: [],
    };
    let table = {};
    
    for ( let acc of value.accounts ) {
        if ( table.hasOwnProperty(acc.id) ) {
            table[acc.id] += 1;
        } else {
            table[acc.id] = 1;
        }
    }

    let finder = id => a => a.id === Number(id);

    for ( let id in table ) {
        let f = finder(id);
        let account = value.accounts.find( f );
        if (table[id] === 1) {
            accounts.individual.push( account );
        } else {
            accounts.joint.push( account );
        }
    }

    return {
        ...value,
        accounts
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and it worked:

```
const arr = [
    { name: 'A', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}, {id: 0, data: {}}]},
    { name: 'B', accounts: [{id: 0, data: {}}, {id: 1, data: {}}]},
    { name: 'C', accounts: [{id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}, {id: 2, data: {}}]},
];


let newArr = [];
for(let i = 0;i < arr.length;i++){
    let join = [];
    let individual = [];
    for(let j = 0;j<arr[i].accounts.length;j++){
        console.log(idInArrayCount(arr[i].accounts,arr[i].accounts[j].id));
        if(idInArrayCount(arr[i].accounts,arr[i].accounts[j].id) > 1){
            join.push(arr[i].accounts[j]);
        }else{
            individual.push(arr[i].accounts[j]);
        }
    }
    newArr.push({
        "name" : arr[i].name,
        accounts : {
            "join" : join,
            "individual" : individual
        }
    });
    function idInArrayCount(array,ID){
        let count = 0;
        for(let i = 0;i < array.length;i++){
            if(array[i].id === ID){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
console.log(newArr);
```

The variable  `newArr` contains the wanted value.

Comment: While this code may work for the question, It is better to provide **_why_** this answers the question. this is a site built on **learning**, not just wring code for other people